# Criando um datepicker Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, datepicker

Estou querendo criar um datepicker conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando crio um, ele fica dessa maneira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Msm quando uso algum exemplo que crie um conforme a primeira imagem, ele acaba ficando igual a segunda imagem.

Quero criar o datepicker igual a primeira imagem, pois acho ele mais fácil para poder selecionar a data desejada e com maior rapidez.

Será que alguém poderia me passar algum exemplo, para criar o datepicker que estou querendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o DatePicker da segunda imagem é do Android 5.0 (Lollipop). Se você testar em dispositivos antigos, ele ficará do jeito da primeira imagem. O melhor e mais fácil a fazer é deixar desse jeito, assim o Android mostra o DatePicker correto conforme a versão do sistema.

Comment: Entendi! Valew Luiz por esclarecer minha duvida!!