# Como criar um DatePickerDialog pre lollipop

Tags: android, datepicker

já fiz de tudo e não consegui fazer um DatePickerDialog como esse...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para versões pre lollipop. O código que estou usando por enquanto:

```
 DatePickerDialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityAddAvaliacoes.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            edtAddData.setText(dayOfMonth+"-"+monthOfYear+"-"+year);
                        }
                    }, year, month,day).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Como eu mesmo respondi nessa pergunta: [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98399/criando-um-datepicker-android-studio). Esse DatePicker é apenas para o Android 5.0 e superior, caso você queira usar em versões antigas, teria que fazer o porte manualmente, mas, felizmente, algumas pessoas já fizeram isso e você pode usar uma biblioteca pronta:

Essa: [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) permite que você use esse DatePicker em versões 4.0 e superiores, o que já atingiria uma grande parcela dos celulares android.

[image]

***Segunda opção:***

Mas, caso você queira algo com uma maior retro-compatibilidade, você pode usar essa: [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) que permite usar esse DatePicker desde a API +9 que é o Android 2.3:

[image]